# Vulkan - Is there need for two different RenderPasses for two different finalLayouts?

Tags: layout, vulkan

vulkan Renderpass object defined also with final layout the rendertarget is transitioned to when render pass finishes. 
Say I have a renderpass for doing rendering task A, but in one case I need to represent the results on screen (final layout is then VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR), and in other case I need to make it ready for another pass (final layout is then VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL), 
Is there need to create two renderpass objects for those two scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render passes also have the initial layout, which specifies the layout the image is in before the render pass starts. This, coupled with the layouts defined for each subpass, cause the render pass system to perform implicit layout transitions for the various subpasses.

So all you need to do is to tell the second render pass that the attachment will be in the present layout, and set the subpass layouts appropriately. And of course, the load-op for the attachment should be to load the data rather than clearing it or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, So I do need to create two similar render passes with one difference - the output layout value.

Comment: @audi02: Well, now you're asking about the *content* of the render passes. Which depends on what they're doing. I kind of assumed that the reason you were thinking of using two render passes is because the second one was doing something that would require being a second render pass, rather than just an additional subpass in the first one.

Comment: Yes, I have to render colored mesh, but in one occasion the final layout should be VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR, and in other occasion it should be VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL.  I was wondering about that I need to create *two* render passes with exactly the same parameters (shades, states, render targets), just because of the need for different final layout.

Comment: @audi02: You're not understanding what I'm trying to say: *why* do you think you need two render passes? Why can you *not* put the commands from the second render pass into the first render pass? If the second render pass is operating on the same attachments as the first, for what reason can you not simply put the drawing commands from the second render pass into the first? I think you're experiencing an XY problem, that you have encountered some problem and you think the solution is to create two render pass operations.

Comment: I guess I miss something in my understanding vulkan. I take your  last comment of using the drawing commands on the same render pass and I will be back after playing with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for @Nicol Bolas I understood that I missed something here, and in order to avoid other newbies to fall into this mistake, I explain here my mistake.

When creating a pipline there is need to set a renderpass handle to VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo::renderPass.

A newbie like me understood that it means that a renderpass is created and coupled with a pipeline and can render only using this pipeline. IT IS ABSOLUTELY INCORRECT. This parameter just inform with what type of renderpass (render target arrangement ) the pipeline should render on. But the renderpass is not coupled to this pipeline. Different pipelines can be used to draw within the same renderpass, and a pipeline can be used with different renderpasses as long as those renderpasses have the similar structure as the one that the pipeline was created according to.

So regarding my question in this post - there is no need for two pipelines, but we can use the same pipeline for being used by two renderpasses.